# Remote desktop after slow internet cannot connect to remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

When my internet connection is running at normal speed I can connect to my Windows server 2008 via RDP. When the connection becomes slow it will just show the loading bar, and say "connecting". So I cancel, and when my internet connection comes back online, Remote Desktop will show "an internal error has occurred". Then I need to restart my server before I can connect to RDP.

Can you help me please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's some issues related to DNS when your internet gets slow try connecting by using the IP address instead of hostname if it turns out fast then you might need a reverse DNS in your zone or you need to configure netbios also you could add the RDP computer to your `hosts` file located in 
`%systemdrive%\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` in the following format :

```
IPaddress ComputerName
```